# How can I determine if a class A inherits from class B without instantiating an A object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection, inheritance

Suppose I want to determine if `Admin` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. One way is to do this is `Admin.new.kind_of? ActiveRecord::Base`, but that instantiates an unused `Admin` object.

Is there an easy way of doing this without creating an `Admin` object?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sure, just compare the two classes:

```
if Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end
```

It is interesting to note that while [`Module#<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3C) will return `true` if `Admin` inherits from `AR::Base`, it will return `false` or `nil` if that's not the case. `false` means that it is the otherway around, while `nil` is for unrelated classes (e.g. `String < Range` returns `nil`).

Comment: And if you are looking for the documentation, as it happens, class Class is derived from Module, so: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.html#M000206

Answer (score 10):

It's pretty simple:

```
Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
=> true
```

Comment: I like this one, which works because class `Class` is derived from `Module`. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.html#M000206

Answer (score 4):

```
Admin.ancestors.include? ActiveRecord::Base
```

Hmm. Well, this works, but we've just learned a nicer way. It seems that [Ruby's *Module* class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.html) defines an [operator `<` for this purpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.html#M000206), and since [class *Class*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Class.html) derives from [*Module*,](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.html) that means `<` will directly test for derived classes.

Answer (score 3):

```
Admin.ancestors.includes? ActiveRecord::Base
```

For direct ancestry you could also use

```
Admin.superclass == ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: This will work, but it is not efficient, as it generates an array of all ancestors and then iterates through it looking for `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: Ah yeah just read the source and it creates a new ruby array which is slightly less efficient. Though it has the benefit of slightly easier readability (figuring out "what does this code do?").